# Programmatically open a Javascript bookmarklet in a window opened by parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent window that opens a child window with some URL. Is it possible for the parent window to programmatically execute a [Javascript bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) in the child window?

Is this possible (If so how?) or is it prohibited due to security reasons?

**Edit**

To clarify,

1) The parent window has code that I write.

2) The child window could be any webpage, most often not of the same origin.

3) I want to be able to open a Javascript bookmarklet in the child window from the Javascript code I write in the parent window.

Comment: Do you mean in code you control in the parent window? E.g., in the code doing the opening? Separately: Are the pages in the parent and child windows in the same origin?

Comment: The browser will not allow the parent window to access the DOM of the child window, if they're not of the same origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The child window could be any webpage, most often not of the same origin.

This is the key point.

No, you cannot access the child window, not even to run a bookmarklet in it.

Answer (score 1):

No, that an arbitrary website does execute javascript in some arbitrary other page is prohibited for security reasons. Fortunately.